# Ftp Downloaded file size is 0 KB

Tags: java, ftp

I'm trying to download all the files in the FTP path to my local system. But the downloaded files are in 0 KB. What would be the problem. Please help me to find the bug. (files are of type *.zip, *.pdf, *.xml)

Thanks in advance.

```
package ConnectFTP;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class FTPDownloader {

FTPClient ftp = null;

public FTPDownloader(String host, String user, String pwd) throws Exception {
    ftp = new FTPClient();
    int reply;
    ftp.connect(host);
    reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
    }
    ftp.login(user, pwd);
    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
}

public void downloadFile(String remoteFilePath, String localFilePath) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath)) {
        this.ftp.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, fos);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void disconnect() {
    if (this.ftp.isConnected()) {
        try {
            this.ftp.logout();
            this.ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FTPDownloader ftpDownloader =
                new FTPDownloader("192.168.3.1", "Adminuser", "password");
        ftpDownloader.listFolders();
        System.out.println("File downloaded successfully");
        ftpDownloader.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void listFolders() {
    try {
        String ftpBasePath = "dev";
        FTPFile[] fileList = ftp.listDirectories("/" + ftpBasePath);
        for (FTPFile file : fileList) {
            listFiles(file.getName());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FTPDownloader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void listFiles(String path) {
    try {
        FTPFile[] fileList = ftp.listFiles(path);
        for (FTPFile file : fileList) {
            String currentFileName = file.getName();
            String localPath = "E:\\FTPFiles\\"+currentFileName;
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localPath)) {
                this.ftp.retrieveFile(currentFileName, fos);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Logger.getLogger(FTPDownloader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioe);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Remove `throws Exception` from from FTPDownloader and use `try-catch` inside the method. That will show you what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that. But Im not getting any exception or errors. Everything works fine and files are downloaded but the size of the files are 0 KB. Thats the issue Im unable to find out.

Comment: Somebody Please Help me in this.......Pls

Comment: has this problem solved? what environment are you using (windows/mac/linux 32/64 bit) ?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for my Question. I have modified my code with some little changes. The given code will get all the files in the given ftp path and stores it in the local directory with the folder wise structure.

The output structure will be like this example:

E:\FtpFiles\2013\November\11222013\*.*

*.* is the files stored with the folder structure as it in the FTP

Operating System : Windows 2008 server (64 bit)

However this will work in all windows FTP servers and move file to local system or given path.

Thanks.

```
package ConnectFTP;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;


class UFTP {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UFTP unftp = new UFTP();
    unftp.Unfile();
}

private void Unfile() {
    try {
        //Current Date, Month, Year Starts
        Date mmddyyyy = new Date();
        String today = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy").format(mmddyyyy);
        String cyear = today.substring(4, 8);
        String month[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
            "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        String cmonthS = today.substring(0, 2);
        int cmonthI = Integer.parseInt(cmonthS);
        cmonthS = month[cmonthI - 1];
        System.out.println("Month : " + cmonthS);
        System.out.println("Year  : " + cyear);
        //Current Date, Month, Year Ends

        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect("192.168.3.5");
        if (!ftp.login("dev", "password")) {
            ftp.logout();
        }
        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
        }
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        String ftpBasePath = "devpath";  //ftp Base Directory
        String localPath = "e:\\FtpFiles\\";

        //create DIR Tree
        //Create Year Dir
        File newDir = new File(localPath + cyear);
        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + today);
            boolean result = newDir.mkdir();
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Year DIR Created");
            }
        }
        localPath = localPath + cyear + "\\";

        //Create Month Dir
        newDir = new File(localPath + cmonthS);
        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + today);
            boolean result = newDir.mkdir();
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Month DIR created");
            }
        }
        localPath = localPath + cmonthS + "\\";

        //Create Date Dir  
        newDir = new File(localPath + today);
        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + today);
            boolean result = newDir.mkdir();
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Today DIR created");
            }
        }

        //creates today's dir
        //destinationBasePath = "e:\\FtpFiles\\" + today + "\\";
        localPath = localPath + today + "\\";
        FTPFile[] fileList = ftp.listDirectories("/" + ftpBasePath);
        for (FTPFile directory : fileList) {
            System.out.println(directory.getName());
            String currentDir = directory.getName();
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles("/" + ftpBasePath + "/" + currentDir + "/");
            if (ftpFiles != null && ftpFiles.length > 0) {
                for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {
                    if (!file.isFile()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println("File is " + file.getName());
                    OutputStream output;

                    //Create Dir Starts
                    newDir = new File(localPath + currentDir);
                    // if the directory does not exist, create it
                    if (!newDir.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("creating directory: " + currentDir);
                        boolean result = newDir.mkdir();
                        if (result) {
                            System.out.println("DIR created");
                        }
                    }
                    //Create Dir Ends

                    output = new FileOutputStream(localPath + currentDir + "\\" + file.getName());
                    ftp.retrieveFile("/" + ftpBasePath + "/" + currentDir + "/" + file.getName(), output);
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }
            }
        }
        ftp.logout();
        ftp.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```